# Certain forms wont fill out Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I am trying to populate PDF forms using Itext 7.

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("example.pdf"), new PdfWriter(RESULT));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
fields.get("Last Name").setValue("Smith");
pdf.close();
```

It works perfectly for 1 form but for another form, it generates a 0kb pdf form that wont open.

This is the pdf that I am trying to fill out but it wont work:
https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-9.pdf?download=1

No matter what I try, this form does not get filled out. I think the problem may be that it has annotations and the fields cant detected.

Can anyone explain to me why that form cant be filled and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Your example file contains a pure XFA form, and it does not have a field named "Last Name".

Comment: When I was testing for that form, I was searching the field called "Last Name (Family Name)" and it did not work. Regarding the XFA thing, how do I best deal with this? Do I "remove XFA" and then use the form or does ITEXT have a specific way to deal with XFA forms?

Comment: Removing XFA won't do the trick because that only makes sense if the form also contains AcroForm fields (and your form doesn't). XFA is deprecated in PDF 2.0, and very few companies support it. Have you already taken a look at iText's [pdfXFA add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfXFA)?

Comment: Im not looking to buy a license or pay for something. This is a project that needs to remain free. Is there any free solutions to populating an XFA form?